# Load 3 drop down based on each other in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to load drop down based on each other. I did as follows:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="drblLanguages" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="drblLanguages_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
        </asp:DropDownList>

  <asp:DropDownList ID="DrpCategory" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DrpCategory_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true" EnableViewState="true">
        </asp:DropDownList>

 <asp:DropDownList ID="DrpEmailTemplate" runat="server" Enabled="false" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DrpEmailTemplate_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
        </asp:DropDownList>
```

**My back end code as follows:**

```
  protected void drblLanguages_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                LoadDataForCategoty();               
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                SendToErrorPage(ex);
            }
        }

   protected void DrpCategory_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                    LoadEmailTemplateToDropDown();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                SendToErrorPage(ex);
            }
        }
```

**In Page_load event**

```
   protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
     {
        try
        {              
            LoadLanguageDropdowns();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            SendToErrorPage(ex);
        }
     }
```

In here when language changed relevant categories are loaded. but when category is changed its always selecting first record ( index -1)  and it calls `drblLanguages_SelectedIndexChanged` event instead of `DrpCategory_SelectedIndexChanged`. it seem drop down is initialized from beginning again. how can I resolve this?

Comment: I think you need to call the LoadLanguageDropDowns() in Page_Load under !IsPostBack block

Comment: I edit my answer check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(!IsPostBack)
{
    LoadLanguageDropdowns();
}
```

Do you try this ? You should load your dropdowns in Page_Load, not in OnInit.. This will load your dropdowns only on first opening and your problem should not appear.

EDIT: You have three dropdowns

```
        <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="LanguageDdl"  OnSelectedIndexChanged="LanguageDdl_SelectedIndexChanged" DataTextField="Title" DataValueField="ID" AutoPostBack="true">
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="CategoryDdl" OnSelectedIndexChanged="CategoryDdl_SelectedIndexChanged" DataTextField="Title" DataValueField="ID" AutoPostBack="true">
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="TemplateDdl" OnSelectedIndexChanged="TemplateDdl_SelectedIndexChanged" DataTextField="Title" DataValueField="ID" AutoPostBack="true">
        </asp:DropDownList>
```

Code behind:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            LanguageDdl.DataSource = new Varmebaronen.AppCode.BO.Object().GetList();
            LanguageDdl.DataBind();
        }

    }

    protected void LanguageDdl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //if query the database for dataSource like in my case here you can
        // take value of the languagedropdown and fetch the category for the current language
        CategoryDdl.DataSource = new Varmebaronen.AppCode.BO.Category().GetList();
        CategoryDdl.DataBind();
    }
    protected void CategoryDdl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TemplateDdl.DataSource = new Varmebaronen.AppCode.BO.Product().GetList();
        TemplateDdl.DataBind();
    }

    protected void TemplateDdl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Comment: @DevT if(!IsPostBack) is the crucial part.

Comment: @DevT you load the dropdowns only in Page_Load of the page in if(!IsPostBack) and remove it the loading from Init and the problem appear again ?

Comment: I loaded `LoadDataForCategoty()` in pageload and kept `LoadLanguageDropdowns()` in init

Comment: @DevT Load the dropdowns only in the Page_Load in 
if(!IsPostBack) delete the code in Init.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61269/discussion-between-mybirthname-and-devt).

Comment: @DevT You load the dropdowns again somewhere, debug the code.

Comment: In my case it seems when `TemplateDdl` index changed it fires `CategoryDdl` index changed event

Comment: you are correct i found my user control is loaded every postback and it cause this problem.. thanks for your help